# error: member access into incomplete type 'AVFormatInternal'

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec, libav, libavformat

I hav eroor in ffmeg lib
error: member access into incomplete type 'AVFormatInternal'
I try to do this

```
AVFormatContext *s;
s->internal->raw_packet_buffer;
```

In libav examples it works.
What i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is because `AVCodecInternal` is defined in `internal.h`

You must add `#include "libavcodec/internal.h"` in your .c file, where `AVCodecInternal` is used.